# "undefined: beego in beego.AppConfig" - How to access Beego configuration parameters

Tags: go, parameters, configuration, beego

As proposed here http://beego.me/docs/mvc/controller/config.md, I add parameters for MySQL user/password and when trying to access them (for example by using

`beego.AppConfig.String("mysqluser")`)

I get an `"undefined: beego in beego.AppConfig"` message. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was caused by a stupid mistake... I forgot to add the beego package... Try the following:

`import "github.com/astaxie/beego"`

Comment: This should be an edit to your question. You can edit your question.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12593858)

Comment: @Prasad Khode that's an answer actually. The problem was solved after I imported the above package.